# iOS - get modal controller's parent controller in iOS7

Tags: ios, iphone, ios7

I have added an UINavigationController into interface builder in Xcode 5, and name its identifier as "importer", then in Home controller, I use it as a modal window, from these code -

```
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"main" bundle:nil];
            UINavigationController *importer = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"importer"];

            [self presentViewController:importer animated:YES completion:nil];
```

It works well, and the importer controller displayed with correct data in its UITableView.
Then when I dismiss the importer controller, I use this code in importer controller -

```
 [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{

        HomeController *p = (HomeController *)self.presentedViewController;
        NSLog(@"home controller = %@", p);
        [p onCompleteImport];

    }];
```

The HomeController is the one who present importer controller, and I want to get HomeController from completion block, but it gave me "null", so how to get HomeController from importer controller? Thanks.

I have tried presentingViewController, parentViewController, presentedViewController, and even self.navigationController.presentingViewController, self.navigationController.presentedViewController, and self.navigationController.parentViewController, all failed.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
HomeController *p = (HomeController *)self.presentingViewController;
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:^{
    NSLog(@"home controller = %@", p);
    [p onCompleteImport];
}];
```

Retain it before using block, because the 'importer' was already dismissed when animation complete.

Answer (score 0):

It's strange, but I found what's wrong with it.

The HomeController is a child controller of MainController, and the presentingViewController of importer controller is "MainController", not what I expected, kind strange, although importer controller is presented from HomeController.

Another problem is "can't load presentingViewController in complete block, coz this time, presentingViewController will be nil"